# Communicating aggregate percentage changes in data without exposing individual contributors

Tags: mean, population, differential-privacy

So i have a dataset that tracks widget production from 100 different factories, each individually owned and highly competitive. Each line contains the factory name, the date of production, and the # of widgets produced.

As expected, some widget factories produce way more widgets than others. In fact, the top few factories typically account for 70% of widget production.

I am the government and hold and see all of this data, but no individual widget factory has all of the data. However, I would like to provide "aggregate" statistics to all widget producers such that they can compare their own factory's performance to the "industry average".

However, I cannot do a simple weighted average, as this would expose the growth rate of the top few factories. Down-weighting the top producers will give me growth rates that correlate with the "total" widget growth rate, but would not have the same magnitude, so I don’t think that number is particularly useful.

What are typical solutions to this issue? I want to show an accurate % change in total industry widget production from week to week, but don't want to put anyone at a disadvantage. This seems like a problem the bureau of labor statistics would run into frequently, for example if they are posting monthly manufacturing data and certain sectors only have a small number of primary contributors to those numbers. Would do they do in these scenarios? How are they "anonymizing" the data while still making it useful?

Comment: This is a differential privacy. (+1)

Comment: @usεr11852 Indeed, it is, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the average from leaking the value associated any individual factory, you would typically use [differential privacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_privacy), for example by adding Laplace noise of scale $\frac{C}{n\varepsilon}$ to your average, where:

- $C$ is the maximum contribution of any given factory (that you have to fix *in advance*, based on your knowledge of the problem space and typical data distributions, not based on the real data)
- $n$ is the number of factories,
- $\varepsilon$ is the desired privacy parameter.

If any factory's value is larger than $C$, you have to *clamp* its value (replace it by $C$). If the values you're averaging can be negative, you also need a lower bound $B$, and the scale of the noise is $\frac{C-B}{n\varepsilon}$.

Now, if only one or a handful of factories have a completely oversized contribution compared to the rest, this noise might be too large to get meaningful results. But if that's the case, you're essentially trying to solve an impossible problem: if the statistic inherently leaks data about large factories when reasonably accurate… the trade-off between accuracy and privacy leakage might be an unacceptable one.